# Cache for subdomains

Tags: asp.net, caching

There are subdomains: **sub1.domain.ru, sub2.domain.ru, sub3.domain.ru, sub4.domain.ru**. On default page there is a code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string subdomain = Cache[key] as string;
    if (subdomain != null)
    {
        Label1.Text = "Your subdomain is :" + subdomain;
    }
    else
    {
        Cache[key] = GetSubDomainName();
        Label1.Text = "Your subdomain is :" + Cache[key] as string;
    }
}
```

Will users see **their** subdomain name in different subdomains(**sub1.domain.ru, sub2.domain.ru, sub3.domain.ru, sub4.domain.ru**) ?

Answer (score 2):

If I can rephrase the question, I think you're asking whether the `Cache` object associated with the application in which the page resides is shared across sub-domains.

The answer is, it depends:

- If each sub-domain is deployed as a
  distinct **AppDomain**, they will have
  their own memory space (**Cache**
  and **Session** will not be shared). NOTE: this holds true even if they share the same App Pool.
- If you have this set up as a single
  **AppDomain** accepting multiple host-headers,
  then it's possible to access this
  page under different sub-domains but
  have one copy of the **Cache** accessed
  by all requests.

Answer (score 0):

But cache i think is global. You should use Session instead...

If you do

```
cache["subdomain"] = getMySubDomain()
```

it will be overwritten everytime, and if you do

```
dim sd as string = cache["subdomain"]
```

it will give you the last saved subdomain independent to the current logged in user...

Why you don´t try with different browser.

Comment: There is an `if` for the `else`. I adjusted the formatting to make it more clear.

Comment: getsubdomainname() - is a custom method. It's for a example only.